# review first post, unable to edit.

Tags: feature-request, review, suggested-edits

I got to review https://math.stackexchange.com/review/first-posts/289264

and I decided that it needed a small edit (adding the terminology tag)

but the edit option was grayed out because there was another (suggested) edit pending.

So my only option was to skip it ( I don't have enough reputation to look in to the pending edits queue).

Can we not change this behaviour?

Just keep posts out of the first post review queue of <3k users when there are edits pending?

Comment: I empathize with your frustration. No one's reviewing is consistently 100% perfect, and often times, I see such reviews still lacking in basic grammar and incorrect formatting. I don't mean to place myself on a high horse, either- I'm sure I make "tag" mistakes every so often. A cool feature would be to have two different checkers review each "first time" question/answer. There are enough reviewers to make that feasible, and we have the technology to ensure (to some degree) that different users are individually revising.